# Forms' submit button, inside another form, doesn't seem to go to the mapping, why?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My Java/Springboot/Thymeleaf app has a form called direct bind. On this form there is a modal that pops up when you click a button, in this modal you can attach a file. The submit button to the modal, does not seem to be registering or sending to the `@Requestmapping`. Any idea why and how to fix this?

I've tried setting the controller up like this instead `@RequestMapping(value="/attachDoc", params="document")`. I've also tried adding `formnovalidate="formnovalidate"` on the submit input. As well as moving it to the same controller file as the original form. Not sure what else to try.

HTML:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal" data-izimodal-title="Upload a Document">
     <div id="newRequiredDocForm">
         <form enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/attachDoc}"  method="post" th:object="${newDocument}">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 text-right"><label class="modalLabel">Type:</label></div>
                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 text-right">
                 <label class="modalLabel">File:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7">
                 <input type="file" name="document" multiple="multiple" style="margin-right:-20px;"/>
               </div>
            </div>
            <br/><br/>
            <div style="text-align: right;"><input type="submit" name="attachNewDoc" value="Submit" class="btn btn-docModal"/></div>
          </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/attachDoc")
public String attachDoc(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="newDocument") Document newDocument, @RequestParam("document") MultipartFile file){
        Document doc=documentRepository.save(newDocument);
        doc.setStorage(storageService.store(file));
        documentRepository.save(doc);
        return  "directBind";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define **`method=RequestMethod.POST`** in your mapping.

By default if you are not specifying any method in request mapping then it will be GET.

You are using `post` method in your thymeleaf but the mapping in the controller is for GET(By default)

So you have to change requestmapping like below.

**`@RequestMapping(value="/attachDoc",method=RequestMethod.POST)`** by specifying POST method.